# MySQL - Deleted 1 billion rows - Load still high and table doesn't respond

Tags: mysql, innodb

i'm using MySQL 5.5 (Percona Server) and i just deleted all records from my InnoDB table, which were around 1.1 billion rows. This took around 3 to 4 days.

That finished 2 days ago, after that i made a simple select (LIMIT 50) on the now empty table:

The select didn't finish, in fact i had to kill it, but it is still (2 days later) in the process-list (`SHOW PROCESSLIST`). Further, the response time of the server is still higher (like commiting takes multiple seconds instead of ~20-100 msec) and the server load is increased.

I'm sure the I/O has gone up, but i can't figure out why.

- What did i do wrong?
- How can i improve the situation?

Maybe this can help: My Configuration is here http://pastebin.com/BvnhcB1X

Comment: As far as what you did wrong - it would have been more prudent to use TRUNCATE over DELETE when removing all rows, especially on a table that size.  Likely would have saved you a few days :)

Comment: yes, i know that now... that wasn't the best thing to do. still the load is still high and the response times are not optimal. any idea on that?

Comment: Did you try to rebuild the indexes and restart de server?

Comment: I don't think restarting the server would be useful, since it is possible that there are pending transactions. How should i rebuild the indexes? How is that done?